# Add a cache to a go function as if it were a static member

Tags: go, memoization

Say I have an expensive function

```
func veryExpensiveFunction(int) int
```

and this function gets called a lot for the same number.

Is there a good way to allow this function to store previous results to use if the function gets called again that is perhaps even reusable for veryExpensiveFunction2?

Obviously, it would be possible to add an argument

```
func veryExpensiveFunctionCached(p int, cache map[int]int) int {
    if val, ok := cache[p]; ok {
        return val
    }
    result := veryExpensiveFunction(p)
    cache[p] = result
    return result
}
```

But now I have to create the cache somewhere, where I don't care about it. I would rather have it as a "static function member" if this were possible.

What is a good way to simulate a static member cache in go?

Comment: Just use a package-level map or similar.

Comment: @Beginner please check my answer as it also handles concurrency race conditions etc.

Comment: @Peter that would be a package-global variable, right? I would prefer to use something local, inside my function. How would I justify a global variable for this?

Comment: @EduardHasanaj yes, I did and upvoted. I am testing the implementation. Why the hurry?

Comment: I am sorry if felt so. Ping me if I can help more:)

Comment: In computer science this is called [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). Using this word to search should bring up interesting results.

Comment: @EduardHasanaj thank you for the input! I am spending some time implementing some of the suggestions. I learned a bunch so far, this is great!

Comment: @marco.m thanks! I did not know that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use closures; and let the closure manage the cache.

```golang
func InitExpensiveFuncWithCache() func(p int) int {
    var cache = make(map[int]int)
    return func(p int) int {
        if ret, ok := cache[p]; ok {
            fmt.Println("from cache")
            return ret
        }
        // expensive computation
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        r := p * 2
        cache[p] = r
        return r
    }
}

func main() {
    ExpensiveFuncWithCache := InitExpensiveFuncWithCache()
    
    fmt.Println(ExpensiveFuncWithCache(2))
    fmt.Println(ExpensiveFuncWithCache(2))
}

output:
4
from cache
4

veryExpensiveFunctionCached := InitExpensiveFuncWithCache()
```

and use the wrapped function with your code.
You can try it [here](https://play.golang.org/p/ZUv0HV86zwZ).

If you want it to be reusable, change the signature to `InitExpensiveFuncWithCache(func(int) int)` so it accept a function as a parameter. Wrap it in the closure, replacing the expensive computation part with it.

Comment: if the initialization is trivial like here, you can use `func init()` to initialize things, so it doesn't need to be called explicitly (from main etc.)

Comment: I think your link got a stray character - but yes here: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#init

Comment: This was really easy to implement and it works great, thanks.

Comment: What if different goroutines were to call the ExpensiveFuncWithCache simultaneously? Is it thread safe? Thx

Comment: @ant1g maps are not safe for concurrent read/write. You should use a lock in that case

Answer (score 6):

You need to be careful about synchronization if this cache will be used in http handlers. In Go standard lib, each http request is processed in a dedicated goroutine and at this moment we are at the domain of concurrency and race conditions. I would suggest a [RWMutex](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex) to ensure data consistency.

As for the cache injection, you may inject it at a function where you create the http handler.
Here it is a prototype

```
type Cache struct {
    store map[int]int
    mux   sync.RWMutex
}

func NewCache() *Cache {
    return &Cache{make(map[int]int), sync.RWMutex{}}
}

func (c *Cache) Set(id, value int) {
    c.mux.Lock()
    c.store[id] = id
    c.mux.Unlock()
}

func (c *Cache) Get(id int) (int, error) {
    c.mux.RLock()
    v, ok := c.store[id]
    c.mux.RUnlock()

    if !ok {
        return -1, errors.New("a value with given key not found")
    }

    return v, nil
}


func handleComplexOperation(c *Cache) http.HandlerFunc {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
        
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Go standard library uses the following style for providing "static" functions (e.g. [flag.CommandLine](https://golang.org/src/flag/flag.go?s=17934:17956#L1033)) but which leverage underlying state:

```
// "static" function is just a wrapper
func Lookup(p int) int { return expCache.Lookup(p) }

var expCache = NewCache()

func newCache() *CacheExpensive { return &CacheExpensive{cache: make(map[int]int)} }

type CacheExpensive struct {
    l     sync.RWMutex // lock for concurrent access
    cache map[int]int
}

func (c *CacheExpensive) Lookup(p int) int { /*...*/ }
```

this design pattern not only allows for simple one-time use, but also allows for segregated usage:

```
var (
    userX = NewCache()
    userY = NewCache()
)

userX.Lookup(12)
userY.Lookup(42)
```

Comment: And my expensive function call would happen in lookup, right?

Comment: Correct. If you are expecting concurrent use, you need to protect the cache map by leveraging the lock.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a generator to create a cacheMap.

Like this:

```
    type cachedFn[K any, V any] struct {
        cacheMap       sync.Map
        getFunc        func(K) (V, error)
    }
    
    func NewCacheFn[K any, V any](getFunc func(K) (V, error)) *cachedFn[K, V] {
        return &cachedFn[K, V]{getFunc: getFunc}
    }
    func (c *cachedFn[K, V]) Get(key K) (V, error) {
          // you logic
    }
```

The use this generator like this:

```
    ExpensiveFuncWithCache := NewCacheFn(ExpensiveFunc).Get
    ExpensiveFuncWithCache(arg)
```

Here is an example: https://go.dev/play/p/guzOWRKi-yp

And go cached decorator package:[gocache-decorator](https://github.com/ahuigo/gofnext)